# Is there a way to display Text when my "circle" is clicked in Ursina Engine?

Tags: python

I am making a quiz game where you can click on the answer and etc.

This is the code:

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()

class Option(Button):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
      model = 'circle',
      texture = 'brick',
      color = color.blue,
      scale = 0.3)


demo_button = Option()
app.run()
```

and when it is clicked, I want text to display for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this be declaring an input action in the class

```
def input(self, key):
    if self.hovered:
        if key == 'left mouse down':
            popup_text = Text("Hello, World!")
            destroy(popup_text, delay=.3)
```

In this case I set the input event up so that when ever the player hovers over with mouse and clicks the right mouse button it then displays the text and destroys its but as you can see there is a delay setting in the destroy method.

Also, if you wish to make the text larger you can by doing some thing like

`popup_text = Text("Hello, World!", scale=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `input()` to detect the click on a button is kind of dumb, `Button` being made to handle that on it's own.
To execute a function on a `Button`'s click, use the `on_click` method :

```py
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()

class Option(Button):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
      model = 'circle',
      texture = 'brick',
      color = color.blue,
      scale = 0.3)

  def on_click():
    doSomething()


demo_button = Option()
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 from ursina import * 
 app = Ursina()
 def Click():
    txt = Text(text="Test",scale = 3,position = (-.05,.05,0))
    destroy(txt,delay=2)

Option = Button(model="circle",texture = 'brick',color = color.blue,scale = 0.3)
Option.on_click=Click

app.run()
```

or this if you really need a class

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()

class Option(Button):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
      model = 'circle',
      texture = 'brick',
      color = color.blue,
      scale = 0.3)
  def on_click(self):
    if self.hovered:
        txt = Text(text="test num 3",scale =3,position=(-.15,.05,0))
        destroy(txt,delay=2)


demo_button = Option()
app.run()
```